# Query value from APEX page item

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm querying two tables to display values in a tabular form on page two, based on a row selected on page one, (the data on page two is editable, relevant to the column on page one.) I created a hidden item on page two to hold the unique identifier from page one.  I'm having trouble however getting the value to work in a "where" clause at the end of my query.  How do you query a page item value in Oracle APEX?

```
select g.GROUP_ID as GROUP_ID,
c.COMPONENT as COMPONENT,
c.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION,
c.MANUFACTURER as MANUFACTURER,
c.MODEL as MODEL,
c.VALIDATED as VALIDATED,
'' as updated_group_id,
g.OBJECT_TYPE as OBJECT_TYPE,
g.Q_LEVEL as QUALITY_CLASS,
g.ASME as ASME 
from tbl_group g
left join tbl_component c on c.group_id = g.group_id
where g.group_id = p2_x
```

P2_X is my hidden page item, group_id is the unique identifier passed from page one, both pulled from the same table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a colon:

```
where g.group_id = :p2_x
```